# Oracle conditional update with Single statement

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement of updating Oracle records with duplicate entries(Which is not known in advance) depending on the condition that I specify, assume my record set as follows,

```
NAME    BRANCH_ID   DEL_FLG  
-----------------------------------
AAA     00931       N  
AAA     00001       N  
BBB     00931       N  
BBB     00008       N  
CCC     00931       N  
CCC     00003       N  
DDD     00931       N  
EEE     00931       N  
FFF     00008       N
```

What I want is only to update duplicate records with BRANCH_ID = 00931 and set DEL_FLG=’Y’

Output should have to be like follows,

```
NAME    BRANCH_ID   DEL_FLG 
----------------------------------- 
AAA     00931       Y   
AAA     00001       N  
BBB     00931       Y  
BBB     00008       N  
CCC     00931       Y  
CCC     00003       N  
DDD     00931       N  
EEE     00931       N  
FFF     00008       N
```

Can this be done with a single SQL? Without using PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this and I think it's what you want.

```
update the_table set del_flg = 'Y'
    where rowid in
    ( select rowid from 
      (select rowid, count (*) over (partition by name) cnt 
      from the_table)
    where cnt > 1)
    and branch_id = 931;
```

Results:
Before

```
NAME                 BRANCH_ID            DEL_FLG              
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
AAA                  1                    N                    
BBB                  931                  N                    
BBB                  8                    N                    
CCC                  931                  N                    
CCC                  3                    N                    
DDD                  931                  N                    
EEE                  931                  N                    
FFF                  8                    N                    
AAA                  931                  N                    

 9 rows selected
```

After

```
NAME                 BRANCH_ID            DEL_FLG              
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
AAA                  1                    N                    
BBB                  931                  Y                    
BBB                  8                    N                    
CCC                  931                  Y                    
CCC                  3                    N                    
DDD                  931                  N                    
EEE                  931                  N                    
FFF                  8                    N                    
AAA                  931                  Y                    

 9 rows selected
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 update the_table set del_flag = 'Y'
    where branch_id in
    ( select branch_id from the_table group by branch_id having count(*) > 1 )
```

or maybe

```
 update the_table set del_flag = 'Y'
     where branch_id = '00931' and name in
     ( select name from the_table group by name having count(*) > 1 )
```

(the question is not completely clear, but as Alex Poole points out, the second one seems to match the output you gave)

Comment: From the expected output (but not at all clear in the description), doesn't the OP want duplicate *names*, and for those then update a specific branh_id?